# Validity of temp credentials by STS Assume role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, boto3

I am calling boto function in AWS to assume a role. I am able to get the temp credentials, but these credentials is max valid for 1 hour. Is there any way to assume the role and temp credentials should be at least valid for 4 hours. Below is the code snippet which I am using

```
    client = boto3.client('sts')
    response = client.assume_role(RoleArn=<Role ARN Name>,RoleSessionName=<Name of Session>)
```

Then I am using the credentials which i got from response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maximum validity you can get with **`assume_role`** is 3600 seconds. 
If you have IAM user credentials, consider using [**`get_session_token`**](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/sts.html#STS.Client.get_session_token).

> By default, temporary security credentials for an IAM user are valid for a maximum of 12 hours, but you can request a duration as short as 15 minutes or as long as 36 hours. For security reasons, a token for an AWS account's root identity is restricted to a duration of one hour.

Refer this [doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp_request.html#stsapi_comparison) for Credential lifetime of different STS API Options.

Comment: get_session_token, i can`t use since I am assuming a role for cross account access.

Comment: Then the max you can get is one hour.